# How do I start a subprocess in python and not wait for it to return

Tags: python, django, r, subprocess

I'm building a site in django that interfaces with a large program written in R, and I would like to have a button on the site that runs the R program. I have that working, using `subprocess.call()`, but, as expected, the server does not continue rendering the view until `subprocess.call()` returns. As this program could take several hours to run, that's not really an option.
Is there any way to run the R program and and keep executing the python code?
I've searched around, and looked into `subprocess.Popen()`, but I couldn't get that to work.
Here's the generic code I'm using in the view:

```
if 'button' in request.POST:
    subprocess.call('R CMD BATCH /path/to/script.R', shell=True)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

Hopefully I've just overlooked something simple.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
subprocess.Popen(['R', 'CMD', 'BATCH', '/path/to/script.R'])
```

The process will be started asynchronously.

Example:

```
$ cat 1.py
import time
import subprocess

print time.time()
subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '1000'])
print time.time()

$ python 1.py
1340698384.08
1340698384.08
```

You must note that the child process will run even after the main process stops.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a wrapper for subprocess.call(), that wrapper would have its own thread within which it will call subprocess.call() method.